# NHibernate context sessions, ASP.NET & threading hodgepodge

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, nhibernate

`NHibernate.Context.WebSessionContext`, otherwise known as `web` [session context](http://nhforge.org/wikis/reference2-0en/context-sessions.aspx), plays nicely with ASP.NET, but only up to a point. As soon as I spin up a new thread, it is no longer able to retrieve current session from a `HttpContext` since there's actually no `HttpContext` for the said thread.

How do you make all this play nicely together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a hybrid session context. [See my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731462/nullreferenceexception-when-initializing-nservicebus-within-web-application-appli/2734036#2734036).

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate sessions are *not* thread-safe, so it might be a better idea to start a new session in your thread.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. And this is exactly why I'm asking.